# Are the elements of a division algebra which commute with all commutators in the center of the algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-rings

I asked this quetion five days ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406669/are-the-elements-of-a-division-algebra-which-commute-with-all-commutators-in-the Some good people have given good comments there.

Comment: This is a lemma in Ancohea's paper http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1969221?uid=3737800&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102278224601. I can not understand the proof.

Comment: Hmm, the proof of the lemma in that paper seems to suggest Ancohea assumes the division algebra is finite-dimensional over the center, but this is never clearly stated earlier in the paper. How about the following 1-sentence proof:  the commutators over $k$ span the space of commutators over $\overline{k}$, so it suffices to treat the case of a matrix algebra, which you can treat by bare hands. QED  

Answer (score 3):

Yes because the division ring generated by commutators is invariant under all inner automorphisms and the result follows from Cartan-Brauer-Hua.